# C# naming conflict: My class "Tag" conflicts with "object Control.Tag"

Tags: c#, winforms, namespaces, naming

I have a custom class called "Tag" inside my VS C# project. I try to access its static method inside a WinForm form, like this:

```
Tag.someMethod()
```

VisualStudio interprets "Tag" as "object Control.Tag {get; set;}". This seems to be silly, but I'm not sure if it should happen and how to resolve it. I prefer not to rename my class, I like this short name. Also I don't want to reference it using the namespace of my project, it is too long. Can anything be done to force VS to recognize "Tag" as my custom class?

Comment: Yes, if you have a property called `Tag` onthe current class, and a separate class also called `Tag`, the C# compiler will prefer the property. The workarounds are to use (part of) the namespace, or to give it another name by renaming it, or giving it an alias (`using X = Tag;`)

Comment: How about renaming your class to something more descriptive? Bland names are generally something to avoid and brevity does not always correlate to clarity

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alias for the namespace if it is big and then use it in the code.

```
using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
Project.Tag.someMethod();
```